# Banner for [tex] and [latex] tags when tex.stackexchange.com goes public

Tags: feature-request, latex

When the TeX and friends site goes into public beta (presumably very soon), could we get a banner on the SO pages for the `tex`, `latex` and related tags (suggestions welcome) to invite people to ask their questions there instead?

I asked a [similar question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237/can-we-get-automatic-advertisement-on-the-so-latex-tagged-page) on the meta for the TeX and friends site, but I guess this is a feature that would be implemented on SO itself...

Comment: For the time being, I've placed a [link on the latex tag-wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=latex&sort=info). However, there are a slew of latex-ish tags (pdflatex, ...) which would have to be addressed one by one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree in this case it would probably be better to have [tex] and [latex] tagged questions there.

We generally don't begin pushing users away from core sites to other sites until those sites have reached public beta maturity in 60-90 days -- and have met our criteria for a survivable public website (this is still being worked out.)

Note that we do run house ads for all public SE 2.0 betas on SO/SF like so:

http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/4066/newse20houseads.png

Updating the tag wiki is a good idea, but just bear in mind, the beta sites are preliminary and may or may not survive public beta.

(we'll release all data as creative commons regardless, so nothing is ever lost.)

Comment: I see. I understand the logic of not pushing people onto the beta sites... But I still feel it would be worth advertising the fact that the TeX and friends site exists, since I would expect a drop off in people who used to answer tex tagged questions here as they went over to the new site...

Comment: what about duplicating a [latex] or [tex] tagged question from SO on TeX and friends (automatically), and also pushing (or pulling) answers to these questions back to SO? is that possible? advisable? good?

Answer (score 2):

Tex.sx is way out of beta and running great. If possible, I'd say *Yay for a banner!*

Comment: +10 if I could.  We are extremely established and would benefit from a stream of new use-cases, ideas, and (obviously) questions!